# Get specific Token from a line using batch Findstr & /f

Tags: batch-file, scripting

so I have a large log file I need to search for a piece of data in, the line in which the data resides isnt always the same so using a Findstr is the only way to get the specific data, but on the other hand I'm not looking for the entire line but rather a specific token, I really am new to this but this is what I have been messing with:

```
for /f "tokens=12 delims= " %%i in (LogOutput.txt) do (
findstr /c:"W_LPS_DUMPS (Scheduled)  Start time:" >> time.txt
)
```

I would like to find that specific phrase in the document, gather the 12th token on the line split by spaces, then write that to a txt file called time.txt. Is this possible or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were kind of close.  Give this a try.

```
for /f "tokens=12 delims= " %%G in ('type LogOutput.txt ^|findstr /c:"W_LPS_DUMPS (Scheduled)  Start time:"') do >>time.txt echo %%G
```

Comment: Thank You So much! That Works!

Comment: Why do you `type` the log file and pipe it into `findstr`? you could simply provide the log file as an argument of `findstr`, which is quicker than piping...

Comment: @Abstract3000, if this answer solved your problem, consider to mark it as the accepted one...

Comment: I'm not allowed to my user feedback is only 14, and I have to have at least 15 to do that, I tried.